# How to shorten this terrible HTTP header parser?

Tags: haskell, parsing, functional-programming, http

I am trying to read a line ending in `\r\n` from a `Handle`. This is an HTTP header.

I’m fairly new to functional programming, so I tend to use a lot of case expressions and stuff. This makes the code very long and ugly.

```
handleRequest :: HostName -> Handle -> IO ()
handleRequest host handle = do
    requestLine <- readHeaderLine
    putStrLn $ requestLine ++ "\n-------------------"
    -- FIXME: This code is bad, and its author should feel bad.
    where
        readHeaderLine = do
            readHeaderLine' ""
            where
                readHeaderLine' s = do
                    chr <- hGetChar handle
                    case chr of
                        '\r' -> do
                            nextChr <- hGetChar handle
                            case nextChr of
                                '\n' -> return s
                                _    -> readHeaderLine' $ s ++ [chr, nextChr]
                        _    -> readHeaderLine' $ s ++ [chr]
```

How can I reduce the amount of case expressions in this code? I thought of using Parsec, but that seemed overkill to me for something this trivial, and I don’t know how well it works with `Handle`s.

Comment: The answer depends on your goal. If you want high performance or an elegant HTTP parser, you should choose different algorithm and libraries.

If you just want to see how your current code can be cleaned up with only structural changes without changing the algoritm, it's a different story. Please specify.

Comment: @nponeccop performance isn’t really an issue. The point is making the code more concise.

Comment: Can't you just use `hGetLine`? There are many alternatives to your code. For example, you can just use `hGetContent` and parse the resulting list.

Comment: @nponeccop `hGetContent` won’t work, since the length of the data isn’t known before the headers are parsed. `hGetLine` won’t work if the headers contain a newline.

Comment: `hGetContent` doesn't require length to be known in advance.

Comment: @nponeccop but I do need to have the length of the HTTP request, otherwise I won’t be able to know the request has already ended. The length of the request body is in the `Content-Length` header.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `hGetContents` to read lazily from a handle, and the [split](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split) package (which will hopefully be bundled into the next Haskell Platform release) provides some nice ways of dealing with lists.

```
import Data.List.Split (splitOn)
import System.IO (hGetContents)

... do
  ...
  contentLines <- splitOn "\r\n" <$> hGetContents handle
```

`contentLines` will contain a lazy list of the "entire contents" of that handle, split into chunks that were originally separated by `\r\n`.

Another approach is to use something like the [conduit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit) package. See, for example, `Data.Conduit.Binary.lines`. Keep an eye on conduit & friends; I get the feeling that within the next year or so the Haskell community will start to agree on the "best" implementation of this sort of abstraction, and then some good tutorials will inevitably follow.

Answer (score 15):

Here I assume you just want to see how your current code can be improved without changing the algoritm.

First of all, give HLint tool a chance to suggest you obvious improvements. In your case the only improvement was that `do` in `do readHeaderLine' ""` was redundant, so not much.

Second, in my opinion many small top-level definitions are better than few large ones. You can still control namespace pollution by not exporting definitions local to the module:

```
import System.IO

type HostName = String

handleRequest :: HostName -> Handle -> IO ()
handleRequest host handle = do
    requestLine <- readHeaderLine handle
    putStrLn $ requestLine ++ "\n-------------------"

-- FIXME: This code is bad, and its author should feel bad.
readHeaderLine handle = readHeaderLine' "" where
    readHeaderLine' s = do
        chr <- hGetChar handle
        case chr of
            '\r' -> do
                nextChr <- hGetChar handle
                case nextChr of
                    '\n' -> return s
                    _    -> readHeaderLine' $ s ++ [chr, nextChr]
            _    -> readHeaderLine' $ s ++ [chr]
```

Next, your `nextChr <- hGetChar handle ; case nextChr of` limes appear twice, so you can extract a function and reduce code duplication.

Thanks to purity, you can do pretty mechanically:

```
foo handle quux bar baz = do
    chr <- hGetChar handle
    if chr == quux then bar else baz
```

Now replace the two fragments with calls to `foo`. Let's start with inner one:

```
readHeaderLine handle = readHeaderLine' "" where
    readHeaderLine' s = do
        chr <- hGetChar handle
        case chr of
            '\r' -> do
                foo handle '\n' (return s) (readHeaderLine' $ s ++ [chr, nextChr])
            _    -> readHeaderLine' $ s ++ [chr]
```

Heh, it didn't work because `nextChr` is only known inside `foo`. No problem, pass it as parameter to `baz` branch and use lambda to catch it:

```
readHeaderLine handle = readHeaderLine' "" where
    readHeaderLine' s = do
        chr <- hGetChar handle
        case chr of
            '\r' -> do
                foo handle '\n' (return s) (\nextChr -> readHeaderLine' $ s ++ [chr, nextChr])
            _    -> readHeaderLine' $ s ++ [chr] 

foo handle quux bar baz = do
    chr <- hGetChar handle
    if chr == quux then bar else baz chr
```

So now you can do the outer one.

```
readHeaderLine handle = readHeaderLine' "" where
    readHeaderLine' s = do
    foo handle '\r' (foo handle '\n' (return s) (\nextChr -> readHeaderLine' $ s ++ [chr, nextChr])) (\chr -> readHeaderLine' $ s ++ [chr])
```

No luck again as first `chr` is nowhere to get from. Fortunately we know it's always '\r', so

```
readHeaderLine handle = readHeaderLine' "" where
    readHeaderLine' s = do
    foo handle '\r' (foo handle '\n' (return s) (\nextChr -> readHeaderLine' $ s ++ ['\r', nextChr])) (\chr -> readHeaderLine' $ s ++ [chr])
```

As line got too long, we can split it, removing another redundant `do`:

```
readHeaderLine handle = readHeaderLine' "" where
    readHeaderLine' s = foo handle '\r' haveCR noCR where
        haveCR = foo handle '\n' (return s) haveCRnoLF
        noCR chr = readHeaderLine' $ s ++ [chr]
        haveCRnoLF nextChr = readHeaderLine' $ s ++ ['\r', nextChr]
```

Now there are more repeated patterns to eliminate: `foo handle` and `readHeaderLine' $ s ++`. To remove `foo handle` we move `foo` back in and remove its `handle` parameter both from applications and definition as it's now accessible from closure:

```
readHeaderLine handle = readHeaderLine' "" where
    readHeaderLine' s = foo '\r' haveCR noCR where
        haveCR = foo '\n' (return s) haveCRnoLF
        noCR chr = readHeaderLine' $ s ++ [chr]
        haveCRnoLF nextChr = readHeaderLine' $ s ++ ['\r', nextChr]
        foo quux bar baz = do
            chr <- hGetChar handle
            if chr == quux then bar else baz chr
```

To eliminate `readHeaderline'` repeated patterns we extract them into `recurse` local function:

```
readHeaderLine handle = readHeaderLine' "" where
    readHeaderLine' s = foo '\r' haveCR noCR where
        haveCR = foo '\n' (return s) haveCRnoLF
        noCR chr = recurse [chr]
        haveCRnoLF nextChr = recurse ['\r', nextChr]
        recurse x = readHeaderLine' $ s ++ x
        foo quux bar baz = do
            chr <- hGetChar handle
            if chr == quux then bar else baz chr
```

This is how far you can get with mechanical code deduplication. Now it's time for heavier weapons. You can still:

- separate recursive code from non-recursive code
- separate monadic code from non-monadic code

The initial `redHeaderLine'` call can be implemented using `recurse` with an extra parameter:

```
readHeaderLine handle = recurse [] [] where
    recurse s x = readHeaderLine' $ s ++ x 
    readHeaderLine' s = foo '\r' haveCR noCR where
        haveCR = foo '\n' (return s) haveCRnoLF
        noCR chr = recurse s [chr]
        haveCRnoLF nextChr = recurse s ['\r', nextChr]
        foo quux bar baz = do
            chr <- hGetChar handle
            if chr == quux then bar else baz chr
```

Now we can inline `readHeaderLine'` as it is only applied once:

```
readHeaderLine handle = recurse [] [] where
    recurse s1 x = foo '\r' haveCR noCR where
        s = s1 ++ x
        haveCR = foo '\n' (return s) haveCRnoLF
        noCR chr = recurse s [chr]
        haveCRnoLF nextChr = recurse s ['\r', nextChr]
        foo quux bar baz = do
            chr <- hGetChar handle
            if chr == quux then bar else baz chr
```

And we can remove duplication of `recurse s`:

```
readHeaderLine handle = recurse [] [] where
    recurse s1 x = foo '\r' haveCR noCR where
        s = s1 ++ x
        rf = recurse s
        haveCR = foo '\n' (return s) haveCRnoLF
        noCR chr = rf [chr]
        haveCRnoLF nextChr = rf ['\r', nextChr]
        foo quux bar baz = do
            chr <- hGetChar handle
            if chr == quux then bar else baz chr
```

Now let's put return value of `recurse` into a local declaration `g`:

```
readHeaderLine handle = recurse [] [] where
    recurse s1 x = g where
        s = s1 ++ x
        rf = recurse s

        g = foo '\r' haveCR noCR
        haveCR = foo '\n' (return s) haveCRnoLF
        noCR chr = rf [chr]
        haveCRnoLF nextChr = rf ['\r', nextChr]
        foo quux bar baz = do
            chr <- hGetChar handle
            if chr == quux then bar else baz chr
```

Our goal is to divorse `g` from `recurse`. You can do it by adding parameters to both `recurse` and `g` and localizing identifiers used only in `recurse` and used only in `g`:

readHeaderLine handle = recurse g [] [] where
    recurse g s1 x = g rf s where
        s = s1 ++ x
        rf = recurse g s

```
g rf s = foo '\r' haveCR noCR where
    haveCR = foo '\n' (return s) haveCRnoLF
    noCR chr = rf [chr]
    haveCRnoLF nextChr = rf ['\r', nextChr]
    foo quux bar baz = do
        chr <- hGetChar handle
        if chr == quux then bar else baz chr
```

Now `recurse` is completely self-contained:

readHeaderLine handle = recurse g [] [] where
    g rf s = foo '\r' haveCR noCR where
        haveCR = foo '\n' (return s) haveCRnoLF
        noCR chr = rf [chr]
        haveCRnoLF nextChr = rf ['\r', nextChr]
        foo quux bar baz = do
            chr <- hGetChar handle
            if chr == quux then bar else baz chr

recurse g s1 x = g rf s where
    s = s1 ++ x
    rf = recurse g s

But `g` is still recursive: it has a nasty `rf` parameter which is an indirect recursive application. We need to move `rf` into `recurse` too. So here comes a trick: convert a function call into a constructor.

`g` can have only 3 return values: `return s`, rf [chr] and `rf ['\r', nextChr]`. We can represent them with a data type and return it instead of calling `return` or `rf`:

```
data Outcomes a b c = RF1 a | RF2 b | Return c

readHeaderLine handle = recurse g [] [] where
    g rf s = foo '\r' haveCR noCR where
        haveCR = foo '\n' (return $ Return s) haveCRnoLF
        noCR chr = return $ RF1 [chr]
        haveCRnoLF nextChr = return $ RF2 ['\r', nextChr]
        foo quux bar baz = do
            chr <- hGetChar handle
            if chr == quux then bar else baz chr

recurse g s1 x = analyzeOutcomes $ g rf s where
    s = s1 ++ x
    rf = recurse g s
    analyzeOutcomes outcomeM = do
        outcome <- outcomeM
        case outcome of
            RF1 a -> rf a
            RF2 a -> rf a
            Return a -> return a
```

Now `rf` parameter is unused, so we can clean the definitions of `g` and `recurse`:

data Outcomes a b c = RF1 a | RF2 b | Return c

```
readHeaderLine handle = recurse g [] [] where
    g s = foo '\r' haveCR noCR where
        haveCR = foo '\n' (return $ Return s) haveCRnoLF
        noCR chr = return $ RF1 [chr]
        haveCRnoLF nextChr = return $ RF2 ['\r', nextChr]
        foo quux bar baz = do
            chr <- hGetChar handle
            if chr == quux then bar else baz chr

recurse g s1 x = analyzeOutcomes $ g s where
    s = s1 ++ x
    rf = recurse g s
    analyzeOutcomes outcomeM = do
        outcome <- outcomeM
        case outcome of
            RF1 a -> rf a
            RF2 a -> rf a
            Return a -> return a
```

Now two more improvements: a) `RF1` and `RF2` outcomes can be joined into one outcome as they are handled uniformly and have the same types; b) the only reason we pass `s` is to return it in `Return` outcome, so we can eliminate `s` argument of `g` too.

```
data Outcomes a = RF a | Return

readHeaderLine handle = recurse g [] [] where
    g = foo '\r' haveCR noCR where
        haveCR = foo '\n' (return Return) haveCRnoLF
        noCR chr = return $ RF [chr]
        haveCRnoLF nextChr = return $ RF ['\r', nextChr]
        foo quux bar baz = do
            chr <- hGetChar handle
            if chr == quux then bar else baz chr

recurse g s1 x = analyzeOutcomes g where
    s = s1 ++ x
    rf = recurse g s
    analyzeOutcomes outcomeM = do
        outcome <- outcomeM
        case outcome of
            RF a -> rf a
            Return -> return s
```

Now `rf` and `analyzeOutcomes` are used only once and `Outcomes` type became the same as `Maybe`. So:

```
readHeaderLine handle = recurse g [] [] where
    g = foo '\r' haveCR noCR where
        haveCR = foo '\n' (return Nothing) haveCRnoLF
        noCR chr = return $ Just [chr]
        haveCRnoLF nextChr = return $ Just ['\r', nextChr]
        foo quux bar baz = do
            chr <- hGetChar handle
            if chr == quux then bar else baz chr

recurse outcomeM s1 x = do
    outcome <- outcomeM
    let s = s1 ++ x in case outcome of
        Just a -> recurse outcomeM s a
        Nothing -> return s
```

Now `s1` and `x` are only used in `recurse` to construct `s`. We can then construct `s` outside of `recurse` and pass it. Also, `g` now can be inlined.

```
readHeaderLine handle = recurse (foo '\r' haveCR noCR) [] where
    haveCR = foo '\n' (return Nothing) haveCRnoLF
    noCR chr = return $ Just [chr]
    haveCRnoLF nextChr = return $ Just ['\r', nextChr]
    foo quux bar baz = do
        chr <- hGetChar handle
        if chr == quux then bar else baz chr

recurse outcomeM s = do
    outcome <- outcomeM
    case outcome of
        Just a -> recurse outcomeM (s ++ a)
        Nothing -> return s
```

Now note that `outcomeM` is just a constant and it is not changed across recursive calls. So we can proceed further with our splitting of recursive and non-recursive code:

```
recurse outcomeM s = f s where
    f s = do
        outcome <- outcomeM
        case outcome of
            Just a -> f (s ++ a)
            Nothing -> return s
```

And duplicate `return $ Just` can be moved inside `foo`:

```
readHeaderLine handle = recurse (foo '\r' haveCR noCR) [] where
    haveCR = foo '\n' (return Nothing) haveCRnoLF
    noCR chr = [chr]
    haveCRnoLF nextChr = ['\r', nextChr]
    foo quux bar baz = do
        chr <- hGetChar handle
        if chr == quux then bar else return (Just $ baz chr)
```

After renaming of nonsense identifiers in definition of `foo` we get:

```
readHeaderLine handle = recurse (match '\r' haveCR noCR) [] where
    haveCR = match '\n' (return Nothing) haveCRnoLF
    noCR chr = [chr]
    haveCRnoLF nextChr = ['\r', nextChr]
    match expectedChar onSuccess onFailure = do
        actualChar <- hGetChar handle
        if actualChar == expectedChar
            then onSuccess 
            else return (Just $ onFailure actualChar)

recurse outcomeM s = f s where
    f s = do
        outcome <- outcomeM
        case outcome of
            Just a -> f (s ++ a)
            Nothing -> return s
```

Comment: Perhaps replace the expression `recurse (match '\r' haveCR noCR) []` with `unfoldM (match '\r' haveCR noCR)`, where [`unfoldM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/monad-loops/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-Loops.html#v:unfoldM) is in the [monad-loops](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-loops) package.

Answer (score 10):

You're trying to read from `stdin` until "\r\n" is encountered? You could just recursively call `hGetChar` until you find the right sequence (the buffer is maintained in reverse order and reversed at the end for efficiency reasons and to allow nice pattern-matching):

```
readHeaderLine :: Handle -> IO String
readHeaderLine h = reverse <$> go ""
    where go :: String -> IO String
          go ('\n':'\r':s) = return s
          go xs = do
            ch <- hGetChar h
            go (ch:xs)
```

Comment: I changed `go s@('\n':'\r':_) = return s` into `go s@('\n':'\r':s') = return s'` so that it wouldn’t include the `\r\n` in the result.

Comment: @RadekSlupik: Ah, good point - I overlooked that the EOL marker is not included in the output. I'll adjust my answer accordingly (you don't need the `s@` part anymore in that case).

Answer (score 1):

Note as Frerich mentioned that one serious antipattern in that code is the use of ++ to build up a list element by element.  That's bad because each time you add an element, ++ traverses the whole list so far, which means building an n-element list takes O(n**2) operations.  It's better to use the ByteString snoc function, or use a difference list, or build up the return string in reverse order and then reverse it.

As for recognizing the \r\n, it's pretty easy to code a straightforward state machine, using a datatype to remember what's been seen so far.  In the code below I build up the reversed output and then reverse it, and introduce a newtype for reversed lists to keep track of when a list hasn't been reversed yet.  "snoc" inserts a new element at the front of a reversed list, which means it will be at the end of the unreversed list.  "snoc" is "cons" spelled backwards and "cons" is the traditional name (from Lisp) for putting a new element at the front of a linked list.

```
import System.IO
-- Seen is the datatype for the current state
-- we don't call it State because that's a commonly used
-- library module
data Seen = SeenNothing | SeenCR
type HostName = String

handleRequest :: HostName -> Handle -> IO ()
handleRequest host handle = do
    requestLine <- readHeaderLine handle
    putStrLn $ requestLine ++ "\n-------------------"

-- below is a datatype we'll use for reversed lists
newtype Reversed a = Reversed a
snoc :: Reversed [a] -> a -> Reversed [a]
snoc (Reversed xs) x = Reversed (x:xs)

-- turn a reversed list back to a normal one
unreverse :: Reversed [a] -> [a]
unreverse (Reversed xs) = reverse xs

readHeaderLine h = do
  r <- f h SeenNothing (Reversed "")
  return $ unreverse r

-- this helper function does the work of building the reversed string
f :: Handle -> Seen -> Reversed String -> IO (Reversed String)
f h state result = do
  c <- hGetChar h
  let r = snoc result c
      go :: Seen -> IO (Reversed String)
      go state = f h state r
  case (state,c) of
    (SeenCR,'\n') -> return r
    (_, '\r') -> go SeenCR
    otherwise -> go SeenNothing
```